# Parse JSON array from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert the following string to an array

```
var string = '["YES","NO"]';
```

How do I do this?

Comment: is array object == array of objects

Comment: Convert string to array? This is already array. Describe your problem in details and tell us what you tried

Comment: This is not a array. This is string. This is what i got first into my javascript  Object {1: "["YES","NO"]"}
And now i want to convert this keys value("["YES","NO"]") into array

Answer (score 14):

use the global JSON.parse method

```
JSON.parse('["YES","NO"]'); // returns ["YES", "NO"]
```

You can also use the JSON.stringify method to write the array back to a string if thats how you are storing it.

```
JSON.stringify(["YES", "NO"]); // returns '["YES", "NO"]'
```

Comment: And the improved readability is the *least* important thing about it.

Answer (score 4):

```
var str= '["YES","NO"]';
var replace= str.replace(/[\[\]]/g,'');
var array = replace.split(',');
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9amstq41/

Comment: `alert( "YES".length );  alert( array[0].length );`

Comment: `var str= '["Are you [[sure?]]","No, not really"]';`

Comment: I would add a `.filter(Boolean)` after the `split` to remove empty string values.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $.parseJSON:

```
var string = '["YES","NO"]';
var array = $.parseJSON(string);
```